# $E\subset V^*\implies E\cong S^*$ for some $S\subset V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We have a subspace $E$ of dual space $V^*.$ I ask, if there is a subspace $S$ of $V$ such that $E\cong S^*$ ?

If $V$ is finite dimensional, then the answer is yes. We just choose dual basis in $V$ and $V^*$ and put $S$ to be a linear combination of vectors coresponding to base in $E.$

1. Dose it hold for arbitrary $V$ and $E$ ?
2. What would happen if $\dim(E)<\infty$ ?

My guess was to start with $E^\perp=\{v\in V:\forall_{\alpha\in E}\hspace{3pt}\alpha(v)=0\}$ and with use of AC choose $S$ such that
$$V=S\oplus E^\perp.$$
Next I have that $V^*=S^*\oplus (E^\perp)^*$.... and I stuck.

If I knew that $V^*=E\oplus(E^\perp)^*,$ then the thm would follow. However I am not sure if it is true.

Comment: About the AC tag, it is used to indicate that the question is about the use or necessity of the axiom of choice; rather than "possible use in a solution".

Comment: @AsafKaragila I will keep that in my mind.

Comment: Great. Note, by the way, that my example works without the axiom of choice too (in which case we cannot prove that $\Bbb{R^N}$ even has a basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, even assuming the axiom of choice.

It is an easy exercise to show that a space with a countable basis is not a dual for anything. Now take your favorite space with a countable basis, look at its dual, and pick an embedding into that dual.

For a concrete example, $\Bbb R[x]$, whose dual is $\Bbb{R^N}$.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, subspaces of $V^*$ are more naturally associated to *quotients* of $V$. If $S \subset V$, you can consider the quotient $V/S$, and then $(V/S)^*$ is [naturally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation) isomorphic to the subspace of $V^*$ given by
$$(V/S)^* \cong S^\perp = \{ f \in V^* \mid f(s) = 0, \forall s \in S \}.$$
No (unnatural) choosing of complementary subspace needed.

Unfortunately, not all subspaces of $V^*$ are duals of quotients of $V$, for the same reasons Asaf outlined in his answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that the last line is correct. If my memory serves me right, $L^1[0,1]$ is not the continuous dual of any Banach space, and can be used to construct a counterexample along the lines of my suggestion.

Comment: @Asaf I was going on from memory, but I haven't done functional analysis in a while. I'll remove it.